# Message: Undefined variable: username

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication

I followed a tutorial on Code Factory for a little simple login script for codeigniter.
I can login now but when i want to show the user via the code

```
Welkom: <?php echo $username ?>!
```

i get the error Message: Undefined variable: username

I Don't know what the problem is so i will post my code when you ask for it.

Thanks

EDIT:

My user model.

```
  <?php
    Class User extends CI_Model
    {
     function login($username, $password)
     {
       $this -> db -> select('id, username, password');
       $this -> db -> from('users');
       $this -> db -> where('username', $username);
       $this -> db -> where('password', MD5($password));
       $this -> db -> limit(1);

       $query = $this -> db -> get();

       if($query -> num_rows() == 1)
       {
         return $query->result();
       }
       else
       {
         return false;
       }
     }
    }
    ?>
```

My login controller:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends CI_Controller {

 function __construct()
 {
   parent::__construct();
 }

 function index()
 {
   $this->load->helper(array('form'));
   $this->load->view('login_view');
 }

}

?>
```

My home controller:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
session_start(); //we need to call PHP's session object to access it through CI
class Home extends CI_Controller {

 function __construct()
 {
   parent::__construct();
 }

 function index()
 {
   if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
   {
     $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
     $data['username'] = $session_data['username'];
     $this->load->view('home_view', $data);
   }
   else
   {
     //If no session, redirect to login page
     redirect('login', 'refresh');
   }
 }

 function logout()
 {
   $this->session->unset_userdata('logged_in');
   session_destroy();
   redirect('home', 'refresh');
 }

}

?>
```

Comment: Always a good idea to also link to the tutorial :)

Comment: Here´s the tutorial link: http://www.codefactorycr.com/login-with-codeigniter-php.html

Comment: Where is your code to actually log the user in and set the session data? You have the code for the model calling the database, but I see no controller referencing that model.

Comment: Look at the tutorial. that code isn't commented. but i am new to codeigniter as i said

Answer (score 2):

```
Welkom: <?php echo (isset($username))?$username :"Guest" ?>!
```

Comment: the error is in dutch Serverfout
Er is een fout opgetreden toen de website http://kees.een-site-bouwen.nl/owrb probeerde op te halen. De server kan offline zijn wegens onderhoud of kan onjuist zijn geconfigureerd.

Comment: Server Error An error occurred when trying to retrieve kees.een-site-bouwen.nl/owrb website. The server may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.

Comment: my user in the database is called bob. but when i am logged in a get the message Welkom: Guest! now. so there is a bigger problem then i thought it was.

Comment: Yup it is because you have not assigned value to `$username` ie `$username = username from db ;` some where before echoing it

Comment: hm i thought i did that. maybe there's a problem in that piece of code. i will check that! thanks

Comment: Yes i did this. for safety reasons i copied the piece of code from the tutorial now. i posted the code in the OP

Comment: @KeesSonnema: What do you think where in your code you are assigning `$username` ? There is no assignment so far I can see.

Comment: hm. i'm very new to codeigniter but i thought it was in the model

Comment: can you post an example on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
Welkom: <?php echo $username ?>!
```

With:

```
Welkom: <?php echo (isset($data['username'])) ? $data['username'] : "Guest"; ?>!
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do a further check in the Home class to see if

```
$data['username'] = $session_data['username'];
```

has been set. Try this instead:

```
$session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
$data['username'] = $session_data['username'];
//$this->load->view('home_view', $data);
echo "username: " . $data['username']; exit;
```

Comment: how do i check this? because i have my login message and logout button on my mainpage. and nothing is happening

Comment: Just replace the code in the Home controller's index() method, with what I have put above. It will no longer display the view (as I have commented that line out), but will just display the username. If you still get a 'username: ' only, then it means that variable is not being set properly. Otherwise, you will get a 'username: john' or something like that.